# Is attaching a name to an Ethereum address a "faux pas?"

Tags: dapps, security, addresses

I'm currently working on a DApp right now, and I was curious if it's considered poor design to include a string with the user's name that is mapped to a particular address. A user who has access to that user's address would thereby have access to the user's name.

Does this design serve as a  potential security breach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like a reasonable attempt at normalizing web3 technologies to the modern web2 framework.

The security issue you may want to look into is  non-unique names being attached to each address. As you know, all Ethereum address are unique (by design) so that no two users can have the same address. If you try to abstract the address away from the interface by simply providing a name instead, you must be make sure that users interacting with each other are not solely relying on a simple, non-unique string (e.g. if Alice sends money to Bob, it may go to another user named Bob (since there are two) when she tried to actually send it to the other one.)